# PHP issue with apostrophe in an URL address

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, urlencode, apostrophe

i have a site with a search form... when you type an apostrophe, the first results page is shown properly with only results which have an apostrophe in the name, but the links of the navigation bar don't work properly: the link is for instance http://example.com/search.php?q=%27&page=2 but when you click the link and the page loads it becomes http://example.com/search.php?q=%2527&page=2 and it confuses the results (yes i could use raw_url_decode() but the first results page would not be in line with the others, because the first should not be decoded)

Should i use some RewriteRules or something... ?

P.S. The same problem occurs if i simply do header("Location:http: //example.com/search.php=q=%27") even if i use raw_url_decode() on the '%27' string or raw_url_encode() or even url_encode() and url_decode()

Even if the solution for the results was in the decoding, i would like to show the URL i want to show, and i CAN'T actually send to a page with %27 in the URL because it always becomes %2527... so please tell me how to change the URL, not the results

Anyway you can see it by yourself by going to echidnavideos.it and searching just ' in the search bar... anf then try to go to page 2 or 3

Comment: can you post more of the code?

Comment: I just send the $_GET['q'] to search in the db
$command = "INSERT INTO searched (query) VALUES ('" . $_GET['q'] . "')";
$query = mysql_query($command);

Comment: @user3390335 That makes absolutely no sense, is deprecated, and is sql injection central

Comment: As it takes '%27' it's not injection and as i said, it works for the first page of results so it must make sense

Comment: Thanks for giving the world a vulnerability to your site

Comment: This is good. Looks like I rustled some jimmies. Fix existing bugs before writing new code. The existing bug is that you are allowing arbitrary content to be passed into your SQL query by just placing $_GET['q'] directly in.

Comment: OP, if you sent the query "(delete from searched)" it would literally delete all rows in your table.  That is then open to SQL injection attacks.  What everyone is saying doesn't make sense is why you are inserting a row instead of a select statement.  Furthermore, using urldecode() and encodeURIComponent with PHP and Javascript, respectively, should solve your issues.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP speaks wise words.

Comment: Ok man i'm sorry, that was the line for saving my results and it works only for me in fact it isn't public. Sorry for the mistake. The actual line is
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%" . $_GET['q'] . "%'"
and actually you're right, it could allow injection, but it doesn't

Comment: Guys i reported the wrong line ok? In fact "insert" doesn't have to do anything with searching. Anyway i think you didn't get the issue: i can handle the query and the GET variable, the problem is when i link to the second page of the results and %27 becomes %2527

Comment: That is still open to attack.  Your query (the value of $_GET["q"]) could be set to %\" and title like (delete from posts) and title like \"%

Comment: You need to make it be "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']) . "%'"

Comment: And you need to be using mysqli_* instead of mysql_*. as mysql_* is deprecated

Comment: Anyway security is not the problem i want to solve... please can you go and see by yourself? http://echidnavideos.it type the apostrophe in the search bar

Comment: Well, that's very unwise of you to post a link to your site when I've posted publicly a how-to to delete your table.

Comment: Use encodeURIComponent when sending the query to PHP with javascript.  Then, use the urldecode() function in PHP to convert it back

Comment: Then tell me how to change the SQL query

Comment: I did, change it to "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']) . "%'"

Comment: Man i would like not to use JS!

Comment: Then use PHP to replace the %2527 to equal an apostrophe.  You can use $newString = str_replace("%2527", "\'", $_GET["q"]);

Comment: Ok I've changed it. Thanks a lot. But the problem i was searching solution to is not solved... please can you tell me a solution without JS?

Comment: Man i know how to do it... you still don't understand. I want the adress bar to show %27 instead of %2527 without using JS, ok? Any wordpress blog search form does it, youtube and facebook do it... they search %27 and it keeps %27 from page to page, without JS

Comment: I posted how to do it with PHP, not JS.  Also, I'm not seeing the %2527 problem on your site

Comment: Man, type an apostrophe in the search form ok? and as u see the results, go down on the navbar and click 2 and go to page 2. What do you see then?

Comment: I posted a new answer that will weed out the problem so that your code will always be using an apostrophe, regardless of the URL.  If this is not satisfactory, post your code so we can see what you are doing.  And when I say post your code, I mean all of it not one or two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some PHP code that will rewrite the occurrence of %2527 and %27 to an apostrophe.  This should be done at the beginning of the code.

```
$newstring = str_replace("%2527", "\'", $_GET["q"]);
$newstring = str_replace("%27", "\'", $newstring);
```

So, do this:

```
// if navbar is needed
$q = str_replace("%2527", "\'", $q);
$q = str_replace("%27", "\'", $q);
if($pages > 1){

    $links = 1;
    $a = array();
```

Comment: The problem is not handling the query string, but the url in the address bar. When i search it through the form it goes $q=%27 but when i click on the link for the second page of the results it goes $q=%2527... and i can't avoid it with urldecode() or raw_url_decode() as i have the same problem if i link the page by header("Location:...");

Comment: The URL should not matter as long as the code is interpreting it as an apostrophe.

Comment: This will not change the URL, it will change the query string that is interpreted by the PHP code.  This will fix the issue

Comment: The problem is that the change in the URL is causing the query string to change from an apostrophe to %27.  This fixes that.

Comment: But i want the URL to be correct, just for an aesthetic need. Why wordpress blogs easily do it for god's sake? I don't wanna handle the issue, i wanna solve it.

Comment: And anyway i think the problem is not the apostrophe, but rather the '%' because %27 changes to (%25)27, and %25 is the '%' which is encoded while linking

Comment: Try this solution.  It may actually fix the URL problem too as it is dissecting the apostrophe code

Comment: Man, i mean... if you type the ' in the search form it goes to $q=%27 but from a link "http:... $q=%27" it goes $q=%2527... there MUST be a way to solve without js and obtaining the CLEAN url, as wordpress blogs and many sites do

Comment: Try this solution.  It is rewriting it to an actual apostrophe.  As long as the $newstring is used in the link to get you to the 2nd/3rd page of results, it should be good

Comment: Man i already use it when printing the query string... but when i physically click the link, there occurs the problem. Can we talk in private or something so that i can paste the entire code?

Comment: I'm not going to help any more until you try implementing this solution.  Otherwise, POST YOUR CODE

Comment: You need to do this for the WHOLE query string, including when it is used in the link to get to other pages.

Comment: The original code before posting here my issue:


$q = $_GET['q'];
$q = str_replace("\'","'",$q);

$q = str_replace("\\\"","\"",$q);

$q = str_replace("\\\\","\\",$q);

$q = supertrim($q);

$q = urlencode($q);


// a link
$href = "http://echidnavideos.it/search.php?q=" . $q . '&page=2';

Comment: The problem is not the current URL, it is the contents of the link you are using for going to the other pages.  This link needs to be cleaned.  Then it will work

Comment: Copy and paste all of the page's code to the original post.

Comment: I can't, i press CTRL + K and even try <pre></pre> but it tells me there are errors... i can't post the code

Comment: Oh my god i got it but it doesn't change the URL! It just changes the variable, you understand?

Comment: It will change the URL!  The problem is the link's URL needs to be changed so that the URL will change.  This would fix that!  Well, obviously you know everything, so if you are not going to implement this, I guess you are smart enough to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Ok i understand now, but the fact is that when i see the source code of a youtube page, it is like <a href="youtube.com/search.php?q=%27"> and it goes to "..?q=%27" while it doesn't in my site. Why?

Comment: They might use urlencode() on the PHP side, then urldecode() when getting the value for PHP

Comment: Man, my link is the SAME of youtube ones, they just make the URL don't change after u click the link... it MUST be something about .htaccess!

Comment: Well, there is a mod_security setting with Apache that allows you to use percentage signs in the URL.  Check this article: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mod-security.user/month=20070601